# @NamedQuery - MySQL - LIKE IN

Tags: mysql, jpa

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM piece p WHERE p.code LIKE '%1740%' OR p.code LIKE '%1938%'
```

I did some looking around and can't find anything similar to a LIKE IN():

```
SELECT * FROM piece p WHERE p.code LIKE IN('%1740 %', '%1938 %')
```

In MySQL, I can do :

```
SELECT * FROM piece p WHERE code REGEXP '1740|1938'
```

But I can't use it with @NamedQuery.

```
KO : select p from piece p where p.code REGEXP :code
incomplete : select p from piece p where p.code in :code
```

Anyone to help me ?

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: Can you try `SELECT * FROM piece p WHERE code REGEXP '1740 $|^1938' ;`
Placing ^ in front of the value indicates start of the line. Placing $ after the value indicates end of line. Placing (.*) behaves much like the % wildcard. The . indicates any single character, except line breaks. Placing . inside () with * (.*) adds a repeating pattern indicating any number of characters till end of line.

Comment: I can't use the key word REGEXP in @namedquery.

Comment: I would like to use `select p from piece p where p.code in :code` but if i replace :code by a string list containing : "%1740%","%1938%", it doesn't work

Comment: So I make it differently with TypedQuery. `StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT p FROM Piece p where p.code LIKE '%1740%' OR p.code LIKE '%1938%' "); TypedQuery<Piece> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql.toString(), Piece.class);`

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not support REGEXP in JPQL.  So you can use LIKE and OR, or use a native SQL query.

If you are using EclipseLink, REGEXP is supported in JPQL.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions